# Enabling gulp triggers on build in project.json for .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

I would like to configure my project build so that it triggers a different gulp task on compile in project.json but I can only set the scripts property unconditionally as far as I can see and I have been hunting high and low online to no effect.

I want to run a different task for Debug and Release modes - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `script` section in `project.json` file, but project.json does not support any conditions. This will be possible in future, when `.csproj` file will be used again instead of `project.json`.

Comment: How do you set up a different file for each?

Comment: @KeithJackson sorry, mixed with publishing, when you can specify path to project.json as command parameter

Comment: How hideously convoluted! :o)